# Format decimal numbers in BI publisher RTF template

Tags: bi-publisher

How to format decimal numbers in BI publisher RTF template

[image]

I have XML tag UNIT_PRICE with value .25 , In the report output it displays as 0n25 instead of 0.25

[image]

The attached picture is here. It has to be 0.25 instead of 0n25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after formatting the number as below

[image]

Note : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/bi12214/bip/BIPRD/GUID-E2904A42-80A1-4086-8A8C-31FDE24389C1.htm#BIPRD3160